# How to prevent locks in redshift. ( Shared lock stopping a write job)

Tags: sql, locking, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse, database-locking

I have a data warehouse which are used by multiple downstream users. They read the data from the redshift table. When they read the data, there is a shared lock enforced on the table. At that time, my daily job which is supposed to write on the table does not write as it cannot put an exclusive lock until the shared lock is clear.

Ideally my write job should take priority over any other read job. Can I enforce this is some way?

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is done by your update process not requiring an exclusive lock or managing the need for locks so that the update process isn't blocked.

Can you describe your update process and which steps are requiring the exclusive locks?

Look at the locks and statements causing them when things are making forward progress. Reworking these parts should allow you to keep you updates moving while these read sessions are acting on the versions of data they started with.

It is also important to not have user transactions that hang around for days on end.  This can happen when interactive sessions are just left open mid transaction.  The also prevents errors due to some sessions seeing very old versions of data.